# Regular expression that does not contain 'auto@'

Tags: regex

I'm working with a system that processes email addresses and need to tell it to not process email addresses that contain 'auto@' using a regular expression.

Example email addresses:

```
us.group-email-name.auto@somedomain.com
us.group-email-name@somedomain.com
```

The regex should only match the second and not the first.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: That's just a simple substring match isn't it? You don't need a regex, but if you want / need to use one, the regex is `auto@` itself? Or are you bound by environment to (1) use a regex instead of substring match and (2) the regex should _not match_ to continue rather then _match_ to abort?

Comment: The environment I'm working with does offer substring match, but, if I used that, it would always match email addresses with 'auto@' in it.  It doesn't support a not operator.  I need it to match strings that don't contain 'auto@' in it.  Therefore I'm looking into regex.

Comment: What environment are you using? Perhaps we could find a way better than regex.

Comment: ^ I second The Guy with The Hat's remark: if it's a known package, we might be able to solve to problem in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you don't have to validate the email addresses *and* there is no way to do it with a quick built-in substring finder, you can use this regex:

```
((?!auto@).)*
```

A far better option would be a simple substring finder method/function, like Java's

```
emailAddress.indexOf("auto@")
```

which returns -1 if it doesn't find a match.